# HTML5 <a> element not centering

Tags: html, css

For some reason, this `<a>` tag won't align to the horizontal center. What needs to be done in order to fix this?

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 60px;
   
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid black;
 color: black;
  
 text-decoration: none!important;
          text-align: center;
 text-indent: 15px;
}

.button:before, .button:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 52%;
}

/* box shape  */
.button:before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 4px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
```

Comment: The text-indent?

Comment: you could put ``text-align:center`` on the containing block (body in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in a DIV tag that has `text-align: center;`:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 52%;
}


/* box shape  */

.button:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"><a href="#" class="button">demo</a></div>
```

Comment: 1.) There is no mention of any library, it's a css and html question. 2.) It's hard to believe that there is any library that removes DIVs which have CSS assigned to them - but even if there is, I would strongly recommend not to use it - what's the use of a library that erases my code?

Answer (score 3):

Used margin: 0 auto; for centering and changed a tag to display: block; Also added a width to it.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 52%;
}


/* box shape  */

.button:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a tag a block element.So rather than `inline-block` use `display:block`.And to center use `margin:0 auto;`

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.myButton {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 52%;
}


/* box shape  */

.button:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
<a href="#" class="button myButton">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use transform to do the trick.

```
.button {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
.button {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 60px;
   
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid black;
 color: black;
  
 text-decoration: none !important;
        text-align: center;
 text-indent: 15px;
}

.button:before, .button:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 52%;
}

/* box shape  */
.button:before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 4px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "a"-Element is contained in another Element. In the case of your example it is in the Body-Element. This Element need to have its elements centered, so you would need to set a rule like this:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 52%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* box shape  */

.button:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px 60px;
   
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid black;
 color: black;
  
 text-decoration: none!important;
          text-align: center;
 text-indent: 15px;
  left: calc(50% - 88px);
}

.button:before, .button:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 52%;
}

/* box shape  */
.button:before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 4px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">demo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change yours `.button` class CSS to this one:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 10px 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 3px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will surely work. Thanks.